# How do I give roles to a person that reacted to my message?

Tags: python, discord.py

In the code below I am trying to give a role to a person whenever they react to my message but this code throws me an error saying that `'int' object has no attribute 'id'` the code says that the problem is with this code: `await user.add_roles(user.guild.id, user.id, role, reason='reason')` how do I solve this issue?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = discord.Client()





@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('ready')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  channel = reaction.message.channel

  await channel.send(f'{user.name} has reacted by using    {reaction.emoji} emoji, his message was {reaction.message.content}')

  role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name = 'Test_Bot')
  
  await user.add_roles(user.guild.id, user.id, role, reason='reason')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: You do not need `user.guild.id, user.id` if you say `await user.add_roles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14449816/dominik) said, you do not need `user.guild.id, user.id` if you say `await user.add_roles`. What is happening is that it is trying to use the `user.id` (an integer) you passed instead of the [user object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User) you use when calling the function to begin with: `await user.add_roles(...)`.

So, get rid of `await user.add_roles(user.guild.id, user.id, role, reason='reason')`, and make it just: `await user.add_roles(role)`.

Fixed code should be:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('ready')

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  channel = reaction.message.channel

  await channel.send(f'{user.name} has reacted by using    {reaction.emoji} emoji, his message was {reaction.message.content}')

  role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name = 'Test_Bot')
  
  await user.add_roles(role, reason='reason')

client.run('TOKEN')
```

TL;DR: Discord.py expects the full member object when you use `add_roles()`. You give it the integer of the member's ID instead.